# Angular material table always delete the first row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a table with some data and a delete function on all rows which works but always delete the first row, doesn't matter if I click the delete button on other rows always delete the actual first row.

here is my code:

```
public deleteRow(recordId) {
    console.log('recordId: ', recordId);    // log: undefined
    const dsData = this.dataSource.data;
    console.log('dsData: ' , dsData);       // log: list all the data I have in table

    // For delete confirm dialog in deleteItem to match the db column name to fetch.
    const name1 = 'id';
    const record = dsData.find(obj => obj[this.Users.id] === recordId);
    const name = 'Delete record with id:' + record[name1] + '?';

    console.log('Record is: ', record);    // log: all the data of the first row
    console.log('Record id is: ' , recordId);  // log: undefined

    // Call the confirm dialog component
    this.confirmService.confirm(name, record,'This action will delete the record!').pipe(
      switchMap(res => {if (res === true) {
        console.log('recordId: ', recordId);  // log: undefined
        return this.httpClientService.deleteRow(record);
      }}))
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.success();
          // Refresh DataTable to remove row.
          this.deleteRowDataTable (recordId, this.Users.id, this.paginator, this.dataSource);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.error);
          console.log(err.message);
          this.messagesService.openDialog('Error', 'Delete did not happen.');
        }
      );
  }

// Remove the deleted row from the data table. Need to remove from the downloaded data first.
  private deleteRowDataTable (recordId, idColumn, paginator, dataSource) {
    this.dsData = dataSource.data;
    const itemIndex = this.dsData.findIndex(obj => obj[idColumn] === recordId);
    dataSource.data.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    dataSource.paginator = paginator;
  }
```

The problem is with the Id as I see in the logs but I can't figure it out how can I fix it

Comment: I think that you need pass the "id" to your function. some like `<td><button (click)="deleteRow(element.id)">delete</button><td>`

Comment: I get an error that id is undefined

Comment: I don't know how is your data, so I don't know what is the exact name of the property in your objects "record": ¿"recordId"? "¿id?"